# В клиент-серверном приложении при публикации сообщения с клиента, оно дублируется

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение. У меня возникла проблема и я никак не могу отследить её корни. Дело в следующем:
У меня есть API метод. Я с устройства, отправляю POST запрос (однако, так как на сервере используют массив REQUEST, впринципе безразличен метод, и я пробовал использовать так же и GET), используя Retroft 2. Метод предполагает размещение сообщения на форуме. В итоге, оно размещается дважды, со временем совпадающим до секунды. Я беру из логов запрос, отправляю его из браузера, юзер агент выставлял как на устройстве, всё работает корректно - только один пост публикуется.

Сам метод:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/index.php?m=topic&action=send")
Observable<ApiResponse> sendPost(@Field("id_topic") long id,
                                 @Field("subject") String subject,
                                 @Field("message") String text);
```

Его вызов:

```
public void sendPost(String subj, String text) {
    Subscription subscription = model.sendPost(args.getLong("topic_id"), subj,
            text)
            .subscribe(new Observer<ApiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("Post wrong", "Error while posted message: " + e.getMessage());
                        activityCallback.makeToast("Сообщение не опубликовано, произошла ошибка");
                    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
                        Log.e("Error:", "getMessaage() or activityCallback is null");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ApiResponse apiResponse) {

                    try{
                        activityCallback.makeToast("Сообщение опубликовано");
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Log.e("Error:", "activityCallback is null");
                    }
                    reload();
                }
            });
    addSubscription(subscription);
}
```

Обработчик onClick:

```
@OnClick(R.id.sendButton)
public void send() {
    if (sendText.getText() == null
            || sendText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        makeToast("Введите текст публикации");
        return;
    }
    presenter.sendPost("Re: Тестовая тема", sendText.getText().toString());
}
```

onClick абсолютно точно вызывается один раз. В логах смотрел - запрос отправляется так же один раз. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: onNext 2 раза вызывается, а вот почему, это вопрос, посмотрите приходит ли одна и та же информация или нет

Comment: да, приходит статус 200, приходит всегда они и один раз

Comment: Добавил логи в onNext - один раз выводятся

Comment: а, хм, тогда может проблема в reload()?

Comment: reload() просто запрашивает эту же самую страничку, ну чтобы вроде как бы обновить список сообщений после публикации своего. Он обнуляет текущий список и запрашивает новый
Всё выглядит довольно просто, и я упорно не могу увидеть проблемы(

Comment: Звучит подозрительно, если честно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребята, возможно это когда-нибудь кому-нибудь поможет. Я в самом начале ещё пути к этой приложухе писал код, чтобы в логах видеть ответ сервера:

```
// Trace serve response
    clientBuilder.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        Log.i("ServerResponse: ", response.body().string());
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });
```

Как видно по коду, отсюда летел ещё один запрос, который я не мог никак обнаружить всё это время. Сыграла невнимательность наверное, благодарю всех, кто задумывался над моей проблемой.